# Show that the sum of the elements on every line of matrix $A^{-1}$ is $s^{-1}$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

We have $A$ $(n×n)$ matrix with complex entries. We know that $\det(A)≠0$ and the fact that the sum of the elements on every line is s. Show that the sum of the elements on every line of matrix $A^{-1}$ is $s^{-1}$.

Comment: what's a line here? What did you try?ù

Comment: I dont have any idea this is the first time I have seen this type of problem.

Comment: You mean row..?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's take $V = (1,1...,1)$

The sum of the elements on every row is $s$ is equivalent to $AV = sV$

Applying $A^{-1}$ in both sides we get :

$V = sA^{-1}V$ and since $s \neq 0$ (otherwise, $V$ would be in the kernel of $A$) you have $A^{-1}V = s^{-1}V$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are not so bad in math...

Comment: Before answering, better urge the questionner to show some effort and present his attempt(s).